# Db Script (Nodejs) Load test in Azure

Tags: azure, load-testing

I am developing application on azure using App service - Mobile App

I've also written db scripts (insert, read, delete, update)  in nodejs to which will trigger every time Mobile App try to sync with db.

Is there any way to test performance of data push and pull in Azure database.

I meant, is there any way to load test my db scrips in Azure ?

I've checked there is a Performance testing section under tools in new Azure portal but that is only for api testing. Also, a person can not test full rest API's on that. It is bound to GET requests only.

Thanks

Surinder

Comment: There's nothing built-in, and how you go about load-testing will ultimately be a matter of opinion (and tool recommendations), which makes this question off-topic. There's no single "right" way to load-test, and no single "right" tool either, whether self-hosted or service-based, OSS or commercial.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to load test your database. Follow next steps:

1. [Download JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) and unpack it
2. Download [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx) and unpack `sqljdbc4.jar` to JMeter's /lib folder
3. Start JMeter
4. On Azure side:

   - select the database
   - at the bottom right select the server
   - go to the configure tab
   - enter the ip address of machine where JMeter lives
5. Add [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to JMeter Test Plan
6. Add [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) and

   - populate database URL there in form of `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server>.database.windows.net:1433/<databasename>;ssl=require`
   - use `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` as driver class
   - provide username in form of `username@server`
7. Add [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler and put your query there.

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter) guide for some more details.